# Batch rename files based on folder name

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator

I'm looking to rename a large number of files based on the folder name in which the file resides.  Most folders only contain one file (usually a PDF but could be Word or other files) and I am looking to only change the file base name and not the extension.

Current folders:
[image: Current folder view]

Preferred outcome:
[image: Preferred outcome]

Note: It's unlikely that there will be two of the same file types in a folder.  I'm keen to avoid sequential numbering to all files but if there is a way of adding sequential numbering only in the event of two or more of the same file types then that would be great (although not essential).

I've had a look at Automator but I'm a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve been using the very powerful paid app A Better Finder Rename for many years for complex file and folder renaming needs. Perhaps this app will help. I think it has a free trial period, too.

You can find it [here](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/).

Disclaimer: I’m an extremely satisfied user. No financial or other connection to PublicSpace.net.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  Your solution worked. I couldn't find a preset configuration which changed the name to the folder name (only an option which added the folder name to the existing file name).  However, the app has the option of running multiple commands so I was able to remove name completely (leaving the extension) and then change the filename to match the folder name.  It's a really good app and worth the $20/£20 as it can do a lot more than my existing renaming app. Available from the Mac App Store (which I prefer as can install on multiple Macs) as well as the website.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. It is a great tool for the toolbox!